# Word/phrase for 'we're all people' - when we aren't

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a novel that has two sentient species: humans and dragons. Both are equally intelligent. The dragons do not think this way, but consider the humans to be beneath them. At one point during the novel, a human cries out to a dragon saying, "we're all people," thus indicating that they're the same, that they have the same intelligence, and that therefore neither is below the other. The obvious problem here, is that dragons are not people - a word which has come to be synonymous with human.

The word 'sentient' would work perfectly, except that it doesn't sound right. "We're all sentient," while conveying the point perfectly, is not something someone would say before being eaten by a dragon.

What word/phrase can I use to convey the meaning of 'equally sentient,' in this situation, and still make it sound natural? (A single word is preferred, but a short phrase will work if necessary.)

Comment: I think [*people*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=animals+are+people%2Cdogs+are+people+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canimals%20are%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdogs%20are%20people%3B%2Cc0) is probably the best word ... just make sure that you've set up the meaning of *people* as *sentient being* earlier in the novel.

Comment: Maybe _sapient_? And we dragons are totally smarter than you smelly humans! :)

Comment: I think it would be best to contrast characters who do and do not consider "people" to be synonymous with "humans". For instance, dragons may generally use the word "people" to refer only to fellow dragons, just as humans do among ourselves. In that context, a human assertion that humans are people as well would be an effort to bridge the mutual disrespect between the species.

Comment: I'd say you need to coin a term -- "sentients", or perhaps "sents"

Comment: @recognizer - I am reminded of the movie Little Big Man, where "grandfather" refers to the people of his tribe as "human beings", while the White Men get another term.

Comment: "I am sentient" will be the last thing I say before a dragon eats me.... Calling us "sapient", however, is just asking for the schoolyard to make this "sappies". Scott Card had some weird system based on Swedish for grades of sapients, but my favourite is David Brin's name for the three species of Earth (humans, chimps and dolphins), "the Terragens". Otherwise I agree with Peter: "people", and set it up beforehand.

Comment: "We're all the ***same***"

Comment: An idiomatic phrase is "We're all God's creatures", but if you don't want to go that route, you can also say, "We're all denizens of Earth" or "We're all citizens of Earth"

Comment: "I am like **you**!" - to which the dragon replies "Yes, I like you... for *lunch.*"

Comment: Is the scene pivotal and heavy with emotion, like when Eowyn faces the chief Nazgul in the 3rd (?) LOTR film? Or is it a swashbuckling adventure type of scene, where the reader it might be receptive to a witty remark from the soon-to-be-eaten? Context may help other answerers.

Comment: @MondoMigs It is the pivotal turning point of the entire novel. So... yeah. It's kind of important. :) The human delivering it is basically the main antagonist.

Comment: @PeterShor I believe your answer may be the best; if you make it a reply I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: TommyMyron, thanks for the clarification. Good call on the suggestion by @PeterShor. Yes I think that would work. Best of luck on your novel!

Comment: You might want to make a distinction between _humans_ and _people_, where the latter is interpreted more generally. That seems to be what the human is trying to say: _You're dragons and we're humans, but we're all __people__!_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We're [equals](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equal?q=equals#equal__9)**.

> A person or thing that is the same as another in status or quality:

Note that the definition doesn't specify the quality. So with a little context, you might be able to imply that he is talking about intelligence.

---

I must say this scene reminds me of Shylock's lines. If you're open to a monolog, I think you could take a little inspiration from Shakepeare. All writers could.

Merchant of Venice, Act 3, Scene 1:

> *Shylock*: ...If you prick us, do we not bleed? If you tickle us, do we not laugh? If you poison us, do we not die? And if you wrong us, shall we not revenge? If we are like you in the rest, we will resemble you in that...